# Angular 2 - Cannot bind data from HTTP Get request

Tags: angular, typescript, get, angular2-observables

I'm new to Angular 2 and having trouble binding some JSON data.  If I run the API url in a new tab I can see the returned JSON, just not via my application.  Below are my service, component, & view files.

Service.ts

```
 public permission(module: string): Observable<Permissions[]> {
    return this.http
    .get('api-url')
    .map((response: Response) => {
       return <Permissions[]>response.json();
       })
}
```

Component.ts

```
_permissionsView: Permissions[];

ngOnInit() {
    this.getPermissions();
}

getPermissions() {
    this._commonService.permission('module')
    .subscribe(
        resultsArray => {
            this._permissionsView = resultsArray;
            console.log(this._permissionsView);
        },
        error => {"Error: " + error }
    )
}
```

Component.html

```
<kendo-grid [kendoGridBinding]="_permissionsView">
            ....
</kendo-grid>
```

Am I subscribing incorrectly?

Comment: Is the `console.log` being printed? And are you seeing any errors in the browser console?

Comment: No the console.log is not being printed and there are no errors being shown in the browser console

Comment: When you open the dev-tools (chrome ?) do you see network traffic for your "api-url"? And perhaps change your "Error -Object" to a console.err(error) loging.

Comment: I'm using IE but its the same, I see the "api-url" in the traffic and get a 200 response / can view the JSON in the Response Body

Comment: Just a guess, if you use Angular 5 or 6, delete the .json() method. The HttpClient does not need it (at least i think so) :-)
And perhaps, just for debug convenience, please add a ".tap(data=>console.log(data)" between the .get and the .map

Comment: Is `get('api-url')` the actual code? Or in your actual code is `'api-url'` replaced with the actual URL?

Comment: Indeed, The .json() is already done by Angular itself.

Comment: Still the same issue with removing the .json method

Comment: So removing the full .map(...) ?

Comment: So, just to make sure: When you open the page, the GET is fired by your app (you see traffic and a response in the dev-tools), but the console.log in the component does nothing.
Wandrille is right, the map is not needed here.
The hard debug way would be to "tap" with a console.log behind the get in the service and before the subscribe in the component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me :

In the service

```
constructor( private http: HttpClient ) {}

getPermissions( params ) {

   const headers = new HttpHeaders()
      .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
      .set('Accept', 'application/json')

   const url = 'http://localhost:5000/api/'  

   return this.http.get(
      url + 'permissions',
      { headers: headers }
   );        
}
```

In the controller

```
this.dataService.getPermissions(param).subscribe( 
   data => {
      console.log('data OK !');
      console.log(data);
      this._permissionsView = data;
   },
   error => {
      console.log('data error !');
   }
);
```

I don't know what is kendo grid expecting for dataSource, did you try wrapping the "kendo grid selector" in a div with a *ngIf="_permissionsView" ? so it gets rendered after your http call completes.

Comment: The `Content-Type` header is irrelevant for GET requests as they don't have an HTTP body

Comment: Yes, that's true, I should have different headers for each action.

Comment: On the right track.  Removed the map / .json methods and adjusted per your suggestions.  In the browser console I am able to see 'Data Ok' and my response body as an object.  However, I now get these errors:

ERROR TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'slice'
ERROR CONTEXT [object Object]
ERROR TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'slice'
ERROR CONTEXT [object Object]

Comment: I think the problem now is binding it to the Kendo UI Grid.  I changed from [kendoGridBinding]="_permissionsView" to [data]="_permissionsView" and the above errors are resolved, response can be seen in browswer console, but no results are shown in my Grid.  States: "0 of NaN items"

Comment: That because this._permissionsView is undefined when the grid is rendered.

Comment: put your kendo grid inside a div like this .  <div *ngIf="_permissionsView" ><kendo-grid [kendoGridBinding]="_permissionsView">
            ....
</kendo-grid></div>

Comment: I have it set up like that but still no luck

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example I just wrote using Kendo UI.

It simulates the web api call returning a observable with a delay of 1000

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kendo-datagrid-example